# Cannot apply color attribute to a lightning-output-field using CSS in LWC

Tags: lightning-web-components, lightning-design-system, css

I am trying to change the color of the `<lightning-output-field>` in LWC using CSS but it doesn't work. I am able to change the background color though. Is there any workaround for this? I don't seem to find any documentation online. Please find my html and css.

**HTML**

```
<template>
       <lightning-record-view-form object-api-name="Invoice__c" record-id={recordId}>
          <lightning-output-field field-name="Name" class="baby"> </lightning-output-field>
          <lightning-output-field field-name="Total_Amount__c"></lightning-output-field>
          <lightning-output-field field-name="Password__c"></lightning-output-field>
      </lightning-record-view-form>
 </template>
```

**CSS**

```
.baby {
   background-color:lightblue;
   color: red;
}
```

**Output:**
[image]

Comment: Does this apply to even ``lightning-output-field`` component? @PhilW

Comment: All LWC components are implemented using the Shadow DOM and therefore do not allow their styling to be affected by their context of use. Unless a component explicitly exposes an API property you can use to affect styling you cannot style it without a hack.

Comment: If I read the [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-output-field/specification) correctly, the attribute name for the MWC version is `field-class` that adds "A CSS class for the outer element, in addition to the component's base classes". Experiment with that.

Comment: @KeithC I tried field-class as well, but unable to change the text color. I am able to change the background color.